# Принять разворот, поворот, движение

Tags: семантика

Возможно ли, по-вашему, сочетать слово "принять" с существительными "поворот, разворот, движение"?
Есть устойчивое сочетание "принять оборот". Оно чаще всего применяется по отношению к абстрактным понятиям: дело, судьба, болезнь. Я же имею в виду вполне конкретные: тело, человек.

Человек принял оборот, разворот, движение.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1062262

В списке значений этого слова в данном случае я имею в виду, по-видимому, 9-е: приобрести какое-либо свойство, вид (подобно позе, положению, тело может принять и разворот, движение). Или, к чему меньше склоняюсь, понимается 12-е значение: произвести действие по значению существительного.

Comment: Вопрос будет общим, если его не сопроводить конкретной фразой, или двумя (по числу значений).

Comment: Такие фразы делают предмет бездушным. Человек - все-таки не бездушен, тело, тоже скорее всего относится к человеку, а бездушное тело - труп. Труп принял форму гроба.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такие примеры из книг:

*Они представляют свою просьбу так, как будто я могу отказаться, но все мы знаем, что обмен может очень скоро **принять поворот**: «Ну ты же сама хотела попасть в шоу-бизнес, а если ты не хотела, чтобы у тебя просили...*

*Если их поведение предсказуемо, менее предсказуемо поведение пожилого англичанина: его благородство и готовность **принять поворот** своей судьбы на грани последнего заката рисуется Кингом с большим тактом и...*

*То же самое справедливо и в том случае, если, начертив круг, **принять движение** по одной полуокружности за противоположное движение по другой, скажем в целом круге...*

Популярна фраза "человек вошёл в оборот(ы)".

Более правильно: человек принял позу при движении/обороте/развороте.

Comment: Здесь приводятся примеры все же по отношению к абстрактным понятиям. А с "движением" вообще в другом значении (значении позиционирования), в котором оно может быть употреблено со всеми словами.

Comment: Все 3 слова являются движениями. Движения не принимаются, а совершаются. Языки так устроены, что нельзя комбинировать любые слова. Во втором примере "принять оборот" = готовность встретить. Слово "принять" не употребляется в значении "совершить" даже с абстрактными словами.